# Can you work remotely in Germany if you have blue card of another country?

Tags: germany, blue-card

I have an EU blue card from Finland and work for a company there. My company allows me to do remote work. My EU blue card allows me to travel freely in EU and visit other countries for 90 days. So can I backpack across Germany while working remotely for the same employer? Do I have to inform anyone about this?

Answer (score 0):

The EU regulations define a cross-border commuter as one who visits his home country at least once a week, and imposes additional requirements.  As long as you stay in Germany for more than a week at a time, then this provision would not apply to you, and you would be able to continue working like this for as long as your employer allows you to.  I did this without problems (except I had the Blue Card for Germany, staying in another country).